# Как при успешной авторизации вернуть роль пользователя?

Tags: spring-security

При успеной авторизации срабатывает :

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}
```

Что возвращает клиенту только status 200 OK. Как правильно вернить роль клиента (USER, ADMIN)?

Возможно ошибка кроется гдето сдесь:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with username: " + username);
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRole());

    UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(), authorities);

    return userDetails;
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(RoleEnum roleEnum) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (RoleEnum userRole : RoleEnum.values()) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.toString()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй этот метод в любом из своих контроллеров

```
public List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthorities() {
    Object principals = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    //Тут нужна эта проверка тк если сразу получить principals без проверки
    //На анонимность пользавателя можем получим NullPointerException
    if (!principals.toString().equals("anonymousUser")) {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User u =
                (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)
                        principals;

       List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new LinkedList();
       authorities.addAll(u.getAuthorities());

       return authorities;
    }

    return new List();
}
```

UPDATE

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
       String authority = grantedAuthority.getAuthority();
    }
    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
}
```

Comment: Мне етот метод вставить в onAuthenticationSuccess?

Comment: Суть задачи в том что клиент получив роль пользователя после авторизации, его обработает и покажет нужный контент

Comment: Этот метод используйте если вам нужно получить роль в контроллере. В вашем примере можете сразу получить роли из `Authentication authentication` используйя метод  `getAuthorities`. У этого списка из `GrantedAuthority` есть метод `getAuthority();`

Comment: Извините пожалуйста но мне все таки осталось не понятно. В onAuthenticationSuccess я только вставляю authentication.getAuthorities(); и ничего более в данном методе мне не нужно?
Потому что таким образом клиент так же ничего не получает....

Comment: да, первый метод для получения ролей уже после авторизации.
Что иммено он не получает? Если  пользователелю вы дали роль то этот метод при авторизации вернет список ролей данного пользователя

Comment: Использую POSTMAN для теста. 
localhost:8080/login
Form-data: username: test, password: test
Возвращает статус OK, спустным Response Body
Скорее всего гдето я в другом месте накосячил...

Comment: Точнее возвращает список всех ролей а не текущего кто авторизировался.

Comment: Попробуй так
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
userDetails.getAuthorities();

Comment: Я добавил часть своего кода, возможно ошибка кроется там. И наче все время возвращает список всех существующих ролей

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49659/discussion-between---and-gvart).